# Create multiple structs then sort by elements

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct

So I have to allow the user to create a certain amount of structs with 5 different types of information, and then sort based on one of those types. For example, they would input all the data and then sort by grade or name. How would I go about creating an array of just the different names or grades across the different structs?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct student
{
    std::string studentName;
    std::string studentIDNumber;
    int currentExamGrade;
    int priorExamGrade;
    double GPA;
};

void createStudent()
{
    int numStudents;
    std::cout << "Enter number of students\n";
    std::cin >> numStudents;

    while (numStudents > 0)
    {
        student name;

        std::cout << "Enter the student's name\n";
        std::cin >> name.studentName;

        std::cout << "Enter the student's ID number\n";
        std::cin >> name.studentIDNumber;

        std::cout << "Enter the student's current exam grade\n";
        std::cin >> name.currentExamGrade;

        std::cout << "Enter the student's prior exam grade\n";
        std::cin >> name.priorExamGrade;

        std::cout << "Enter the student's GPA\n";
        std::cin >> name.GPA;

        numStudents -= 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    createStudent();

    int choice;
    std::cout << "How do you want to sort the list?\n (Enter 1 for name, 2     for ID number, 3 for current exam grade, 4 for prior exam grade, 5 for GPA\n";
    std::cin >> choice; 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: So, Captn, where's your array to be sorted? You read student alright, but after reading one, you discard the data and read another.

Comment: That's part of my question

Comment: Ok. Time for you to read about [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) - look over examples too.

Comment: One step at a time. First get the input working, then worry about sorting. Garbage in, garbage out. Garbage in, you sort garbage. Why debug sorting garbage?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I assume you don't know the in-built sort functions in C++. Take a look at [std::sort()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

**Take Input :**

[input values into struct array + printing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965004/input-values-into-struct-array-printing-out)

**Now to make an array of structs :**

[How do you make an array of structs in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468128/how-do-you-make-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

[Creating an array of structs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239220/creating-an-array-of-structs-in-c)

**Now to sort these arrays :**

[Sorting a vector of custom objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380463/sorting-a-vector-of-custom-objects)

**How to approach this problem :**

`std::sort()` allows you to give custom functions based on which non-tivial objects are comparable. Example of one such function is :

```
bool gpa_comparision_function (student s1,student s2)
{
    return s1.GPA < s2.GPA;
}
```

It takes argument as 2 students that need to be compared by the sorting function and returns the ordering of students s1 and s2 based on GPA.

This is why the statement `s1.GPA < s2.GPA` is important.

So if the student **s1 has GPA = 5.0** and **s2 has GPA = 4.0** we want the order to be s2,s1 (ascending) so this **function returns false, stating that s2 should come before s1.**

So in the call of the sorting function :

```
sort (arr_of_students,arr_of_students+N,gpa_comparision_function);
```

notice the 3rd argument, `gpa_comparision_function`, this is telling the in-built function to use our comparison function.

**Talk is cheap show me the code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
struct student
{
    std::string studentName;
    std::string studentIDNumber;
    int currentExamGrade;
    int priorExamGrade;
    double GPA;
};
bool gpa_comparision_function (student s1,student s2)
{
    return s1.GPA < s2.GPA;
}
bool currentExamGrade_comparision_function (student s1,student s2)
{
    return s1.currentExamGrade < s2.currentExamGrade;
}
int main ()
{
    // Create an array of structs
    student arr_of_students[100]; // A better way will be vector<student>

    // Take input
    // ...

    // Now lets sort, assuming number of students is N
    // Based on GPA
    sort (arr_of_students,arr_of_students+N,gpa_comparision_function);

    // Based on currentExamGrade
    sort (arr_of_students,arr_of_students+N,currentExamGrade_comparision_function);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you stepped on the providing the code path, at least go all the way - show him how to read into those structures and **explain to him what is happening**. Otherwise this is an exercise of vanity at best or reputation wh..ing at worst - it has nothing to do with helping him learn.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi I have added the explanation for the use of custom comparision function. I am not going to explain how the input is to be taken. I will find a link a provide it with the answer